# Content Gating - Paywall Experience

Tags: usability, research

Is anyone able to provide examples of companies that pay gate content on their website? Possible case studies you've used when implementing something along these lines? The only sources we've looked into include news companies like NYT, Harvard Business Review, as well as other sites like Medium, and Consumer Reports.

Some background: The company I work at currently operates in a health and wellness vertical where the market is flooded with this particular content. We've really bottlenecked ourselves comparing our content with news companies like New York Times but I worry that this is not a valid comparison. We want to understand how competitors and non-competitors approach gating content and possible considerations when doing so. Kind thanks!

Comment: I imagine you mean "...comparing our content with **news** companies like New York Times...", right? They were established over 150 years ago, so not really "new" ;)

Comment: @maxathousand - Correct. Thank you for pointing out the confusion! Was worded a bit weird.

Answer (score 1):

You might consider looking at paid newsletters and blogs with limited free content and further paid content. A great example is Stratechery, in fact [here's an article](https://stratechery.com/2020/disneys-integration/) that explains a bit more how Integrators at all sizes are able to survive in the world of Aggregators.